# Single Layer Perceptron Error while optimizing and minimising cost using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, perceptron

I thought to execute single layer perceptron concept using tensorflow. The input, excepted output,  weights and bias all are defined in proper way. But while running the program the error is throwing during Optimization and Minimizing the Cost.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 200
display_step = 50

# X must be 1X5
# Y must be  1X3
# w must be  5X3
# B must be 1X3
train_X = np.random.rand(1,5)
train_Y = np.random.rand(1,3)

#
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 5])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 3])

W = tf.Variable([[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0]])
b = tf.Variable([0.0 ,0.0,0.0])


pred = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W), b)



cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y,2))

optimizer =tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


avg_set = []
epoch_set = []


with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(training_epochs):

        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})
        #Here the error is throwing from above line



        if (i+1) % display_step == 0:
           cc = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})
           #Again here also  the error is throwing from above line

           print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (i + 1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(cc), \
                "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b))

           avg_set.append(cc)
           epoch_set.append(i + 1)

    print("Optimization Finished!")
    training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})
    print("Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n')

    plt.plot(epoch_set,avg_set,'o',label = 'SLP Training phase')
    plt.ylabel('cost')
    plt.xlabel('epochs')
    plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Please help me for getting out of this error. Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: line 41, in <module>
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})                                                                                                     
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_1
  [[Node: Variable_1/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Variable_1)]]

Error is like above @FlyingTeller

Comment: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_1
  [[Node: Variable_1/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Variabl

Comment: Please click the edit button under your question and append the traceback to the end of your question. Use code formatting for the traceback. It will be much more readable

Answer (score 0):

I found the error is from `with tf.Session() as sess:`  Before `for()`y loop and removing that, making separate declaration of the session. It worked

Here is the code which will work.

main.py

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 1000
display_step = 50
# taking input as array from numpy package and converting it into tensor

# X must be 1X5
# Y must be  1X3
# w must be  5X1
# B must be 1X3
train_X = np.random.rand(1,5)
train_Y = np.random.rand(1,3)

#
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 5])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 3])

W = tf.Variable([[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0]])
b = tf.Variable([0.0 ,0.0,0.0])


pred = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W), b)



cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y,2))

optimizer =tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


avg_set = []
epoch_set = []

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(training_epochs):
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})


    if (i+1) % display_step == 0:
       cc = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})
   #check what it thinks when you give it the input data
       print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (i + 1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(cc), \
            "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b))

       avg_set.append(cc)
       epoch_set.append(i + 1)

print("Optimization Finished!")
training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})
print("Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n')

plt.plot(epoch_set,avg_set,'o',label = 'SLP Training phase')
plt.ylabel('cost')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: More likely the issue is that in your question you were missing `sess.run(init)`?